# Selecting values to populate the combobox using Modelform

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want to get all the country names in a list so that i can set it it as source of a dropdown.

My modelform class looks like below

```
class UserExtForm(ModelForm):
    countries = Countries.objects.values('countryname').filter(countryname__isnull = False)

    class Meta:
     model = UserExtras
     fields=['phone','aboutme','countries']
```

I am trying to fill countries object with all the country names, but when the html form is displayed the dropdown is filled with text 'Countries object'. Please help me by pointing out what is here.

Thank you very much

Comment: This doesn't look correct to me. Try to specify a proper field for `countries` and then restrict it with `countries.queryset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    countries = models.CharField(max_length=200) //whatever

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.countries
```

taken from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) :

"It’s important to add **str**() methods to your models, not only for your own convenience when dealing with the interactive prompt, but also because objects’ representations are used throughout Django’s automatically-generated admin."